# How to exclude node_modules from buildin VS Code CSS linter

Tags: visual-studio-code, csslint

VS Code reports CSS linter warning from files in `node_modules`. How can I disable checks in `node_modules`?
This is my `jsconfig.json` file (if it matters):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
  ]
}
```